# Uploading files >2GB to CKAN results in Nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ckan

Using a CKAN [production source install](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/installing/deployment.html), I try to upload files via API or Web interface. The performance is good, and I successfully uploaded files up to around 2.5 GB. Now I need to upload a file that is about 4 GB, but I get a `502 Bad Gateway` from *nginx*.
I think I can exclude the nginx config as a root source, since I temporarily proxied to a simple web app I build to test the file upload. While I could upload big files there, I'm still not 100% sure.

Obviously, I adapted the storage settings in the `ckan.ini`

```
ckan.max_resource_size = 100000
```

- The `nginx.log`shows:

```
2023/02/28 09:58:51 [error] 27692#27692: *1684 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.111.111.111, server: my-domain-name.de, request: "POST /dataset/test-data/resource/new HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataset/test-data/resource/new", host: "my-domain-name.de", referrer: "https://my-domain-name.de/dataset/test-data/resource/new"
```

- And the `uwsgi.sterr.log` shows

```
Tue Feb 28 09:58:50 2023 - *** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 1 (pid: 25434, try: 1) ***
Tue Feb 28 09:58:50 2023 - HARAKIRI !!! worker 1 status !!!
Tue Feb 28 09:58:50 2023 - HARAKIRI [core 0] 127.0.0.1 - POST /dataset/test-data/resource/new since 1677578279
Tue Feb 28 09:58:50 2023 - HARAKIRI !!! end of worker 1 status !!!
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 25434) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 28408)
```

Which led me to increase the `harakiri` value in the `ckan-uwsgi.ini`. The funny thing is that this leads to the `uwsgi.sterr.log` no longer showing any error, although it seems to persist and `nginx.log` does not change at all.

I also played around with `post_buffering` (disabled it in nginx then) which also did not solve the issue.

Any ideas what I could do about this? Thanks in advance

My current nginx config looks like this:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=500m;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx_proxy 1 2;

server {
    client_max_body_size 10000M;
    client_header_timeout 10080;
    client_body_timeout 10080;

    server_name my-domain-name.de;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_cache_valid 30m;
        proxy_cache_key $host$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;

    proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
    proxy_send_timeout 10080;
    proxy_read_timeout 10080;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 20m;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;

        # In emergency comment out line to force caching
        # proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = my-domain-name.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain-name.de;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```